# Update in Merge behaves different? It doesn't get the context_info() while Insert does

Tags: sql-server

I created the following two test tables with a trigger to log all the action (Insert, Delete and Update).

**Set up tables and trigger:**

```
-- drop table test; drop table testLog
create table test (id int identity primary key, x int);
create table testLog (idx int identity primary key, Action varchar(10), id int not null, 
    x_deleted int, x_inserted int, uid uniqueidentifier);
go
-- Trigger to log the changes
create trigger trigger_test on test
    after insert, delete, update
as
declare @id uniqueidentifier = context_info();
print @id;

insert testLog (id, Action, x_deleted, x_inserted, uid)
select  isnull(d.id, i.id) ,
        case when i.id is not null and d.id is not null then 'Updated'
             when d.id is not null then 'Deleted'
             when i.id is not null then 'Inserted'
        end ,
        d.x ,
        i.x ,
        @id
from    Deleted d
        full outer join inserted i on i.id = d.id;

set context_info 0;
go
```

Now insert some sample data

```
set context_info 0
insert test (x) values (10), (20), (30), (40), (50);
SELECT * FROM test;
SELECT * FROM testLog
go
```

The following statements work fine. The correct `context_info()` is saved in the log table.

```
begin tran
declare @newid uniqueidentifier = newid()
-- 
set context_info @newid
print @newid
insert test(x) values (1)

set context_info @newid
update test set x = 2 where id = 1
SELECT * FROM dbo.testLog;
rollback
go
```

However, only insert part of the `Merge` got the value in `context_info()`?

```
begin tran
declare @newid uniqueidentifier = newid()
-- 
set context_info @newid
print @newid;

with v as (select * from (values (1, 11), (2, 22), (6, 66)) v (id, x))
merge test as t using v on t.id = v.id
when matched then update set x = v.x
when not matched by target then insert (x) values (x);

SELECT * FROM dbo.testLog;
rollback
go
```

The `uid` of the last two updates got zeros.

Answer (score 1):

Don't set context_info to zero in the trigger. Why would you do that in the first place - it is not the trigger's responsibility to "clean up". The merge statement will cause the trigger to execute for inserts separately from updates. Did you not notice the multiple "prints" in the results pane? That should have been a big clue.